# jquery steps add listener to the next button

Tags: jquery, jquery-steps

In the jquery steps, When a user clicks next, I want to make sure all the blanks required are filled, otherwise, an alert will popup.
  For example, in one steps, there are 6 checkboxes and the user needs to choose at least one, how to add the event listener to next button?

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at *Events* section [here](https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/wiki/Settings#events). There is `onStepChanging` event.

So you can add the event listener like this:

```
$("#example").steps({
    // options
    // ...
    onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex) {
        if (!validate()) {
            // alert and stop when some validation failed
            alert("Error");
            return false;
        } else {
            // proceed
            return true; 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Great! 
As an addition: If you want to handle only clicks on the next button, you could check 
`if (newIndex > currentIndex) {
// do something
}` inside the `onStepChanging` function.